# Exercise 3.8b) of Silverman's "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves"

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{C}$ be an elliptic curve. In exercise 3.8a) of chapter III, Silverman states that there is a lattice $L \subset \mathbb{C}$ and a complex isomorphism of groups $\mathbb{C}/L \cong E(\mathbb{C})$. From this, he asks the reader to prove that one has $deg([m])=m^2$ and $E[m] \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $, where $[m]$ denotes the usual multiplication by $m$ map in the elliptic curve.

Now, in exercise 3.8b), Silverman writes:

> Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve with $char(K) = 0$. Using (a), prove that
>   $deg[m] = m^2$. [Hint: If $K$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{C}$, there is no problem. Reduce to this case.]

Hence, my question is: **How can one reduce the problem to the case where $K \subset \mathbb{C}$?**

I am (vaguely) aware about the existence of techniques like the Lefschetz principle for algebraic geometry type problems, which would solve this issue, but surely this is overkill for such a problem. I also know that we can't embed any field of characteristic $0$ into $\mathbb{C}$ (something like $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ where $X$ is a set of cardinality $> 2^{\aleph_0}$ should be an example), so I don't really see how to attack this problem. Any help?

Comment: I believe you can resolve your issues in the following way: choose a model $f(x,y,z) = 0$ for $E/K$, where $f\in K[x,y,z]$ is homogeneous. Then in fact, the model you chose for $E/K$ defines an elliptic curve $E'/\Bbb Q(\{a_i\})$, where the $a_i\in K$ are the coefficients of $f$. But it should be clear that $E'_K\cong E$ (and that this isomorphism is defined over $\Bbb Q(\{a_i\})$), so there is no danger in working with $E'$ instead of $E$. There are finitely many $a_i$, so you have an embedding $\Bbb Q(\{a_i\})\to\Bbb C$, and this allows you to work with $E'_{\Bbb C}/\Bbb C$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am having troubles seeing how this helps. The idea is to instead view $E$ as an elliptic curve $E'$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\{ a_i \})$, right? Then what do you mean by $E'_K$?

Comment: Right. By $E'_K$ I mean the base change of $E'/\Bbb Q(\{a_i\})$ up to $K$: in algebraic geometry terms, $E'_K := E'\times_{\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q(\{a_i\})}\operatorname{Spec}K$ (as a $K$-scheme). In more elementary language, you simply think of $E'_K$ as the elliptic curve defined by the same equation as $E'$, but now considered as an elliptic curve over the base field $K$ (remember that the field the curve is defined over is part of the data of the elliptic curve).

Comment: Hmm, then what is the difference between $E$ and $E'_K$? They are both elliptic curves defined by the same equation and over the same base field. We would like to get $E$ isomorphic to some $E'$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}(\{a_i \})$ in order to reduce to the previous exercise, right?

Comment: The point is that $E$ and $E'_K$ are isomorphic over $K$, but $E'$ is defined over a field $L = \Bbb Q(\{a_i\})$ which embeds into $\Bbb C$:  what you're doing is choosing a way to view $E$ as coming from an elliptic curve over $L$. Then if you know that multiplication by $m$ on $E'$ induces multiplication by $m$ on $E'_K\cong E$ (this is a consequence of the group law being defined over $L$), and that the degree of $[m] : E'\to E'$ is the same as the degree of $[m]_K : E'_K\to E'_K$, it is enough to work with $E'/L$ (and in this case you know the result from part a).

Comment: I see it now, thank you!